# chmod 777 on local server not working

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

i have a ubuntu 10.10 box on my local network and sshing with my mac what i did is chmod 777 the www directory recursively so that i can use my fav ide to develop on it.

i did this

```
sudo chmod 777 /path/to/file -R
```

in terminal it didnt return anything so im guessing it worked.

i'm using coda on the mac and btw i have ftp turned on , on the ubuntu server so i remotly connected to it using a local ip when i try to create a folder in the www folder it keeps saying

```
Could not create folder named “untitled folder”.
Server said: Permission denied.
Error -140: remote mkdir failed
```

same goes for trying to create anything.

how do i bypass this to make it work?

thanks

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/file i think. I really prefer chown to chmod in this case tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `777` on an server with an ftp is **not safe**, so unless it's a very isolated network I'd suggest using `700` and **changing the user** (`chown`) or `770` and changing the **group** (`chgrp`) to manage the permisions if you are developing with some other users.

So if the ftp user you are using is for example `myftpuser`

```
sudo chown -R myftpuser /path/to/file
sudo chmod -R 700 /path/to/file
```

Should work.

The wikipedia article on [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) may be relevant too